# Is Android's requestLayout() right for layout animation?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is the `requestLayout()` method the right tool to create an animated layout in Android?

We worked some years with Adobe/Apache Flex and know the two methods `invalidateProperties()` and `commitProperties()`. It seems Android's `requestLayout()` and `layout()` serve a similar purpose. But the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html) mention there is a overhead.

```
public class Paginator extends ViewGroup {
    private float animatedCurrentPage = 1;
    private final ObjectAnimator objectAnimator;

    public Paginator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "animatedCurrentPage", 0f);
    }

    public void jumpToPage(int page) {
        objectAnimator.cancel();
        objectAnimator.setFloatValues(animatedCurrentPage, page);
        objectAnimator.start();
    }

    public void setAnimatedCurrentPage(float animatedCurrentPage) {
        this.animatedCurrentPage = animatedCurrentPage;
        requestLayout(); // <== queue an update of the layout
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // measure children here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r, final int b) {
        // layout children here
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html rather than rolling your own?

Answer (score 0):

I think "invalidate()" should by call instead [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

> Drawing is handled by walking the tree and rendering each view that
>   intersects the invalid region. Because the tree is traversed in-order,
>   this means that parents will draw before (i.e., behind) their
>   children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear in the tree. If
>   you set a background drawable for a View, then the View will draw it
>   for you before calling back to its onDraw() method.
>
> Note that the framework will not draw views that are not in the invalid region.
>
> To force a view to draw, call invalidate().